# Multirom Nexus 7 question

Tags: nexus-7

I have a Nexus 7 (wifi) with Multirom. I can install a .zip Rom or a Ubuntu image whithout wipe the data and Boot one or another.

But I don't know what image have I to download from your download page.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to follow the steps as detailed in this post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=38300214&postcount=104 .

Quoting the original post:

1. Requirements: You'll need MultiROM installed with recovery from at least 22nd of February. You can find downloads and installation instruction in in MultiROM's thread (post #2 on this page: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011403), as soon as you have it all installed, come back to this post.
   Free space needed: a little over 1 GB.
2. Downloads: You'll need two ZIP files from this daily build page. a) Base system: raring-preinstalled-armel+grouper.zip (~32 MB). b) Ubuntu data: raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip (the biggest one, ~372 MB)
3. Installing base: Reboot to recovery and got to Advanced->MultiROM. Select "Add ROM" option. Choose these settings: a) Choose ROM type: Android/Ubuntu touch. b) Share kernel with Internal ROM: Don't share. c) Install location: Wherever you wish to install it.
   Click Next, then select ZIP file as ROM source, and choose the smaller ZIP file with base system (raring-preinstalled-armel+grouper.zip). Proceed with installation. Do *not* reboot after installation! Installing on USB: if you get to screen which wants you to "Set up the size of disk images", set the size of data.img to something bigger - 1500mb should be enough.
4. Installing Ubuntu data: Select List ROMs in MultiROM menu in recovery, then select the ROM you've just created (probably named something like Ubuntu_Touch...) and choose Flash ZIP option. Select the bigger ZIP file (raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip) and flash it. Beware, this ZIP file then can't be used to flash Ubuntu without MultiROM, as it is modified in the process to suit MultiROM needs.
5. Profit: Ubuntu touch developer preview is now installed. Keep in mind that this *really* is just a preview, so pretty much nothing will work. Looks good though.

Answer (score 1):

Its very very easy all you have to do is make sure you are unlocked and rooted.

1. Go to play store
2. Install the MultiROM manager app
3. Fill out the info on the install/update card and hit install

THATS ALL!!!